# how to provide the same product for free for a specific time after it was purchased in woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress

how to provide the same product for free for a specific time after it was purchased in woocommerce? For example, GPL Plugin selling sites are providing one year free updates once a plugin was purchased

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [downloadable product](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/digital-downloadable-product-handling/) in WooCommerce with an expiration date by editing the "Download Expiry" field. So if you set the "Download Expiry" field to 365 days, users will have access to the file for a year.

You can check [WooCommerce Subscriptions](https://woocommerce.com/products/woocommerce-subscriptions/) and [WooCommerce Memberships](https://woocommerce.com/products/woocommerce-memberships/) if you would like to have advanced functionality like a membership area and lower price for renewals.